# How to set default capacity for lists

Tags: c#, console

So I tried making a todo list app making use of for loops and nested if statements. I created a function for adding tasks deleting and showing the whole list, but when I run the code I only get to input a task once even though I set the list capacity to what the user wants.

This is my code and what I've tried so far:

```
namespace mycsharpproject1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> todo = new List<string>();

            void addt()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter task to be add");
                todo.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            void removet()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter task to be removed");
                todo.Remove(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            void showt()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(todo);
            }

            string user_input = Console.ReadLine();
            
            if (user_input == "r")
            {
                if (todo.Count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("you have no tasks in your list");
                }
                else
                {
                    removet();
                }
                
            }
            
            if (user_input == "a")
            {
                int i= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (i == todo.Capacity)
                {
                    addt();
                }
                
            }
            
            if (user_input == "s")
            {
                showt();
            }
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no outer loop, so it will only ever run through once.

Comment: a) List<T> doesn't really need a capacity. b) Console.WriteLine(todo); doesn't what you think it does.

Comment: It's never too early to read through the C# naming conventions, by the way

Comment: Where did you "set the list capacity to what the user wants"?

Comment: And why does the title of your question ask how to set the capacity, and the body of your question claim you set the capacity?

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code a little bit. It's because there's no loop in your code, it only runs once. And the last like Console.ReadKey just reads an input and exits.
And the list doesn't need a capacity to be set if you exactly need that amount of item in yoru list. So, try this one.

```
 class Program
    {
        static List<string> todo = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            todo = new List<string>();
            while (true)
            {
                string user_input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (user_input == "r")
                {
                    if (todo.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("you have no tasks in your list");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        removet();
                    }
                }
                if (user_input == "a")
                {
                    addt();
                }
                if (user_input == "s")
                {
                    showt();
                }
            }

        }


        static void addt()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter task to be add");
            todo.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        static void removet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter task to be removed");
            todo.Remove(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        static void showt()
        {
            todo.ForEach(q => Console.WriteLine(q));
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please touch on the last function